# MDX Calculated Members not recognised

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am using Mondrian.

When I use following query :

```
with MEMBER [Added_On].[2011].[4].[tot] AS
 '[Added_On].[2011].[4].[4]+[Added_On].[2011].[4].[5]'
  select
 {[Added_On].[2011].[4].[tot] } on columns, 
{([Measures].[Count])} on rows from Transactions
```

I get error which says :

```
Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Added_On].[2011].[4].[tot]' not found in cube 'Transactions'
```

Could someone please point out errors?

`Added_On` is a time dimension.
I used schema workbench to make a schema for this.
Rest has been working fine till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add the name of the level of the member 2011 in the expression of your calculated member:

```
[Added_On].[name of the level of 2011].[2011].[4].[tot]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,tried this but it did not work. But my earlier query started working when i named the hierarchy same as dimension name. I do not understand why!

Comment: @user1589502 Did you try ``[Added_On].[name of your hierarchy].[name of the level of 2011].[2011].[4].[tot]`` before renaming it?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : The query started working when i named hierarchy same as dimension name. Still looking for better solution ...